# How to create local private git branch from a remote repo?

Tags: git

I am from perforce background. Now I have moved to a new team where we are using GIT and I use a Windows 7 box.

As per our branching strategy we create a new branch for every feature from a branch called 'develop'. So for us develop is like the trunk in perforce/svn from where I would like to keep merging into local branch at regular interval.

This is I what I am trying to achieve:
Create my private branch, say 'develop-user-private'. Being in a new team I will do a lot of research(dummy code changes to understand the application logic while debugging) in this branch. Therefore, I will not push anything back to server but only commit to local repo. 
I only want this branch on my local machine but do not want it on server, I mean only a private local branch.

This is what I did

> cd c:\GitRepo
>
> git init
>
> git clone https://user@gitrepourl

Upto this it looks good based on the readings I have done. Now when I run

> git branch develop-user-private

it fails with error

> "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master' "

Questions:

1. How to create this local private branch from 'develop'?
2. What will be the command to take(merge) latest from 'develop' into this new branch?

Comment: Do a git tutorial before you start working with it. Init is not required when cloning

Comment: Oh! Where ever I read first step everyone say is git init.

Comment: That is for when you are creating a new repo

Answer (score 1):

**Git** will not create a master branch until you commit something.
As suggested in the comments, `init` is not required when cloning.

1. Clone the repository: `git clone https://user@gitserver...
2. Change to repository: `cd <repository-name>`
3. Create a local branch: `git branch <local-branch-name>`
4. Do all the adds/edits you want to do and commit the changes: `git commit -am "commit message"`
5. Go back to master branch: `git checkout master`
6. Do a pull on master: `git pull origin master`
7. Merge your local-branch into master: `git merge <local-branch-name>`
8. Push to origin master branch: `git push origin master`

Comment: I would suggest going through each command and know what they do.